# PHP7 issue : socket_sendto occurred "Unknown host"

Tags: php, docker, php-socket

> Q :
> Please let i know why `socket_sendto` function occurred `Unknown host` error

#### env

```
centos 7.9
php-fpm 7.4 AND php-fpm 8.1
in docker container
```

#### /etc/hosts

```
<docker net ip>     <docker container id>
127.0.0.1           nd.domain.com
```

#### execution

```
php -q SERVER.php
```

#### source

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php

// error_reporting(E_ALL);
// set_time_limit(0);
// ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '0.0.0.0';
$port = 80;
echo "server now start\r\n";

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or dir("create failed this socket");

if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
    echo 'Unable to set option on socket: '. socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . PHP_EOL;
}


socket_bind($socket, $address, $port) or dir("Failed to bind to (".$address.":".$port.")");
echo "server binded\r\n";





$messageBuffer = "";

$clients = [];
while (true){

    if (@socket_recvfrom($socket, $messageBuffer, 2048, MSG_WAITALL, $ip, $port)) {
        $address = "$ip:$port";
        echo "Receive data : " . $messageBuffer . " FROM " . $address. "\r\n";

        if (!isset($clients[$address])) 
            $clients[$address] = array();
     
        $data = "hello-world";
        $client_ip = gethostbyname($address);
        echo "callback - send to " . $client_ip . "\r\n";
        if (@socket_sendto($socket, $data, strlen($data), 0, $client_ip, $port)) {
            echo "sendto ok";
        } else {
            echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket))."\r\n";
        };
    } else {
        echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket))."\r\n";
    };

    



        // $clients[$address]->handlePacket($buffer);
}

socket_close($socket);

//socket_close 

// namespace cgiServer;

    // include_once './server_fn.php';
    // include_once './socketManager.php';
    // include_once './socketManagerSessionCtl.php';

    // // 무한정 실행하기 위해 시간한계를 0으로 설정한다.
    // set_time_limit(0);

    // // 대기할 IP 주소와 포트번호를 설정한다
    // $unit = new \cgiServer\server\manageUnit('192.168.35.29', 9000);

    // //서버 실행
    // $unit->serverOpen();
    // exit;
?>
```

#### server log

###### with php-fpm 8.1 (display error on)

```
server now start
server binded
Receive data : hello world FROM 123.123.123.12:12345
callback - send to 123.123.123.12:12345

Warning: socket_sendto(): Host lookup failed [-10000]: Unknown error -10000 in [err-path] on line 47
Unknown error -10000
```

###### with php-fpm 7.4 (display error off)

```
Receive data : 0101010101! FROM 123.123.123.12:12345
callback - send to 123.123.123.12:12345
Unknown host
```

Comment: Remove the @ sign before `socket_sendto()` to **not** suppress errors and warnings!

Comment: @MarkusZeller 
Warning: socket_sendto(): Host lookup failed [-10001]: Unknown host

Comment: `0.0.0.0` has no DNS entry. You could add it to your /etc/hosts.

Comment: @MarkusZeller thx. i was set that file but I'll try it
maybe i was wrong to modify.

Comment: to '0.0.0.0  domain.com'

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a special address and is synonym for "any local address", or `INADDR_ANY`. It's not routable, as such it doesn't need a DNS entry.

Comment: @HonkderHase I don't know what I do to solve this problem

.

Comment: `$client_ip = gethostbyname($address);` you're assuming that you're sending to a domain name, but you actually send to 123.123.123.12 - remove that function call and the message will vanish. Oh, and use `$address` instead of `$client_ip` of course

Comment: @HonkderHase
I replaced $client_ip with $address, but it didn't solve.
Is this kind of error related to the docker network settings?

Comment: Also imaginable.. Docker has some networking weirdness built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$client_ip` and `$address` returns `123.123.123.123:12345`

> `$ip` returns `123.123.123.123`

so i replace like that

```php
@socket_sendto($socket, $data, strlen($data), 0, $client_ip, $port)
```

to

```php
@socket_sendto($socket, $data, strlen($data), 0, $ip, $port)
```